# How to avoid the direct access in opencart?

Tags: opencart

Typing the common folder structure in the URL the site shows the all folder and the file...
Please Give an idea to restrict the direct access..
Do i need to modify the .htaccess

http://demo.com/catalog/view

like this

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the .htaccess file in that directory.

```
Options -Indexes
<files "*.tpl">
Deny from all 
</files>
```

[This has more information.](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/)